# Algorithm Full-DFS output not as expected

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I copied Python code DFS and full-DFS from 6.006 and this code make me confused, its result not run as expected, please help me, thank you

```
    def dfs(Adj, s, parent = None, order = None):
    if parent is None:
        parent = [None for v in Adj] 
        parent[s] = s 
        order = [] 
    print(f's:{s}')
    print(f'Adj[s]:{Adj[s]}')
    for v in Adj[s]:
        if parent[v] is None:
            print(f'parent[{v}] is None:{parent[v]}')
            parent[v] = s 
            dfs(Adj, v, parent, order)
    order.append(s) 
    print(f'dfs order:{order}')
    print(f'dfs parent:{order}')
    return parent, order

def full_dfs(Adj):
    parent = [None for v in Adj] 
    order = [] 
    print(f'full_dfs:{parent}')
    print(f'full_dfs:{len(Adj)}')
    print(f'full_dfs:{range(len(Adj))}')
    for v in range(len(Adj)):
        print(f'{v}')
        if parent[v] is None:
            parent[v] = v
            dfs(Adj, v, parent, order)
    return parent, order

adj = [[1],[2,3],[4],[4],[]]
par,order = full_dfs(adj)
print(f'{par}')
print(f'{order}')
#
#*******************Output***************************
#full_dfs:[None, None, None, None, None]
#full_dfs:5
#full_dfs:range(0, 5)
#0
#s:0
#Adj[s]:[1]
#parent[1] is None:None
#s:1
#Adj[s]:[2, 3]
#parent[2] is None:None
#s:2
#Adj[s]:[4]
#parent[4] is None:None
#s:4
#Adj[s]:[]
#dfs order:[4]
#dfs parent:[4]
#dfs order:[4, 2]
#dfs parent:[4, 2]
#parent[3] is None:None
#s:3
#Adj[s]:[4]
#dfs order:[4, 2, 3]
#dfs parent:[4, 2, 3]
#dfs order:[4, 2, 3, 1]
#dfs parent:[4, 2, 3, 1]
#dfs order:[4, 2, 3, 1, 0]
#dfs parent:[4, 2, 3, 1, 0]
#1
#2
#3
#4
#[0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
#[4, 2, 3, 1, 0]
#
#
#** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
#Press Enter to exit terminal
```

My question is, why its result is [4, 2, 3, 1, 0] rather than [4,2,1,0] or [4,3,1,0], because Depth first right?

In my opinion, [4, 2, 3, 1, 0]  meaningless, do you agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code visits all nodes. "depth-first" does not mean "first-only". It means that before looking to sibling nodes, it will first look to children nodes. But its purpose is to visit all nodes.

All nodes are visited by your code because `parent` records which nodes are visited, and which not yet, and if they are not yet visited, the loops in both `full_dfs` and `dfs` ensure they are. And when a node is given to `dfs`, it eventually gets appended to `order`, so it is expected that all nodes end up in that list.

Secondly, a node is only added to `order` when all other nodes that are reachable from that node have been visited (through recursion). This is what is called a post-order traversal, since the action on the node is performed *after* the same action has been done on all its successors/children.

Now to the example graph:

[image]

`dfs` recursive calls are made to go from node 0 to 1 to 2 to 4. At that stage there are no more successor nodes, so 4 is appended to `order`, and that deepest `dfs` call returns to get back to the execution context of `dfs` where the current node is 2. Also there we find there are no other successors, so 2 is appended to `order` and also that `dfs` call returns. We get back to the execution context of `dfs` where the current node is 1.

Here we have another successor (second iteration of the loop), and so another recursive call is made where 3 is the current node. Although this node has a successor (4), that node has already been visited (its `parent` has been set), so 3 is appended to `order` and execution returns to the execution context where 1 is the current node.

For node 1 there are no other successors, so 1 is appended to `order` and `dfs` returns to the original execution context of `dfs` where the current node is 0. This node has no other successors, so 0 is appended to `order`.

We can visualise this process a bit where each "box" represents an execution context of a function. Execution goes from top to bottom. When a function returns, its execution context ends (the box closes) and execution continues in the surrounding "box":

```
+-- full_dfs() --------------------------------+
|  parent[0] = 0                               | 
|  +-- dfs(s=0) ----------------------------+  |
|  |  parent[1] = 0                         |  |
|  |  +-- dfs(s=1) ----------------------+  |  |
|  |  |  parent[2] = 1                   |  |  |
|  |  |  +-- dfs(s=2) ----------------+  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  parent[4] = 2             |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  +-- dfs(s=4) ----------+  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | order.append(4)      |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  +----------------------+  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  order.append(2)           |  |  |  |
|  |  |  +----------------------------+  |  |  |
|  |  |  parent[3] = 1                   |  |  |
|  |  |  +-- dfs(s=3) ----------------+  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  order.append(3)           |  |  |  |
|  |  |  +----------------------------+  |  |  |
|  |  |  order.append(1)                 |  |  |
|  |  +----------------------------------+  |  |
|  |  order.append(0)                       |  |
|  +----------------------------------------+  |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Hope this clarifies the process and why you get [4, 2, 3, 1, 0] as output: it is the post-order DFS traversal for your graph when starting at 0.